# TFS Build Defintion in VS 2013

Tags: build-definition

Guys can anyone will explain me the use of the parameter's like automated test, run settings , analyze test impact, (each of them) etc present under Test in process section of Build Definition in TFS for Visual studio 2013. I am a fresher and new to this technology so can anyone explain me this in detail.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general and basic question. And most is related to the concept.
Such as run settings.

> Unit tests in Visual Studio can be configured by using a
>   *.runsettings file.

*analyze test impact*

Used to determine which tests should be run since a previous build, only for manually test on TFS2013, more details please refer this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286589(v=vs.120).aspx).

Because of the limitation of length, no more tautology here. If you are a totally fresher to test in TFS, you could take some time go through all the topics in this link [Testing the application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182409(v=vs.120).aspx). Which include all the answers you want and can help you quickly,comprehensively understand knowledge in this area.

Comment: Hi @SurajPardeshi , any update or this？ Did my reply helped or gave a right direction?

Comment: Yes, It did to some extent but i wanted to know the use of other parameters present in Build Definition which we use to build our project and now after 3 months i know all of them.:-)